# How to insert new module into Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I have following code using Onsen UI

```
ons.bootstrap();

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'service', '$http', '$q', function($scope, service, $http, $q) {


}]);
```

I wonder how I can add new module like ngCookies so that I can access any $injector provided in that module.

Comment: I got error when I tried something like ons.bootstrap(['ngStorage']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen','ngCookies']);
```

No need to use ons.bootstrap(); and obviously in your index.html the html tag should be like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but it still din't work. Got some error and the proper UI cannot be loaded.